# Unicode character to be used as an ellipsis in TypeScript function names?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am in the process of developing a code generator. Its sources are certain XML documents created for other purposes. Sometimes the generated function names are way too long. I have experimented with several solutions, but in the end I just have to crop them. Now I need some indicator in the name that such a cut happened.

Like an ellipsis as suffix: `selectGrade1RestrictedInPhysicallyStrenuousActi…()`

But neither ellipsis nor dots are allowed as characters in a TypeScript function. Any idea what to use instead?

Comment: If your names may start with same string you'd better use `<trimmed name>$<hash>` like `myVeryLongFuncti$2F4B8A` so it's guaranteed to be unique

Comment: @Dimava Good point. However, so far I have limited the function name length to 50 characters. I am pretty sure that no two functions will start with the same 50 characters. So for the time being, I prefer to have functions that look nice, which is important for my use case.

Comment: the thing is, it's *much more likely* then you think it is - if you ever have postfixes anywhere, like `myVeryLongFunction` vs `myVeryLongFunctionFactory`, you'll have a guaranteed overlap

Comment: @Dimava Thanks! Fortunately I only have (short) prefixes (like `select`), no suffixes. Now I see that I should have provided more context in the first place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best I found so far is the greek character `·` which looks like a dot. Usage:
`selectGrade1RestrictedInPhysicallyStrenuousActi···()`

> That’s a valid identifier according to ECMAScript 6 / Unicode 8.0.0.
>
> However, it is not a valid identifier as per ES5. You may want to avoid it if support for older JavaScript engines is a concern.

https://mothereff.in/js-variables#selectGrade1RestrictedInPhysicallyStrenuousActi%C2%B7%C2%B7%C2%B7

Fortunately Visual Studio Code does not complain at all about that character. Unlike e. g. `ͺ`.